# I'm trying to search for "sections" of text in my Cisco ACE load balance config

Tags: linux, sed, grep, load-balancing, configuration-files

I need to find out how to search for complete sections of my Cisco ACE load balance configs. I'm trying to search for a server-farm and then show all of the config for that before the next serverfarm. This is all in plain text, below is an example of what the text might look like.

```
serverfarm host SERVERFARM1-HTTP
  probe TCP_8080
  rserver SERVER1 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER2 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER3 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER4 8080
    inservice
serverfarm host SERVERFARM2-HTTP
  probe TCP_8080
  rserver SERVER1 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER2 8080
    inservice
```

In the above example there are two serverfarms one "SERVERFARM1-HTTP" with four servers in it and the other "SEVERFARM2-HTTP" with only two servers in it. Ultimately I'd like to be able to search somehow for SERVERFARM1-HTTP and see all the rservers under it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Note, I'm using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n '/serverfarm host SERVERFARM1-HTTP/,/serverfarm host SERVERFARM2-HTTP/p' sample.csv
```

output:

```
serverfarm host SERVERFARM1-HTTP
  probe TCP_8080
  rserver SERVER1 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER2 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER3 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER4 8080
    inservice
serverfarm host SERVERFARM2-HTTP
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

With sed, parameterized, making sure that the first line of the next serverfarm is not printed and that also the last serverfarm in the list gets printed:

```
$ farm='SERVERFARM1-HTTP'
$ sed -n "/$farm/"'{:a;N;$p;/\nserverfarm.*$/!ba;s/\(.*\)\n.*$/\1/p;q}' infile
serverfarm host SERVERFARM1-HTTP
  probe TCP_8080
  rserver SERVER1 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER2 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER3 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER4 8080
    inservice
```

`-n` makes sure nothing is printed unless explicitly instructed to. The rest works as follows:

```
"/$farm/"' {   # Start of block we want to print
    :a         # Label to branch to
    N          # Append next line to pattern space
    $p         # If we're on the last line: print

    # If the last line in the pattern space is not the start of a new block, branch to a
    /\nserverfarm.*$/!ba
    s/\(.*\)\n.*$/\1/p   # Remove the last line and print the pattern space
    q                    # Quit
}
```

Or with awk (and almost certainly not very elegant):

```
$ farm=SERVERFARM2
$ awk "/$farm/"' { fl=1; print; next } /serverfarm/ && fl { exit } fl { print }' infile
serverfarm host SERVERFARM2-HTTP
  probe TCP_8080
  rserver SERVER1 8080
    inservice
  rserver SERVER2 8080
    inservice
```

Commented:

```
# On the starting line of the block we want, set flag, print and go to next cycle
"/$farm/"' {
    fl = 1
    print
    next
}

# If the line matches serverfarm and the flag is set, exit
/serverfarm/ && fl {
    exit
}

# If the flag is set, print line
fl {
    print
}
```